# move_uploaded_file function is not uploading into server

Tags: php, ajax

file is not uploading into my server, I am using  move_uploaded_file
 function, i got output as Your file was uploaded successfully. but
file is not thare in that location.

image.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', '#profile_photo', function(){
        var file_data = $('#profile_photo').prop('files')[0]['name']; 
        var email_id=document.getElementById('email_id').value;
        var filename=document.getElementById('profile_photo').files[0]['name'];
        form_data.append('file', document.getElementById('profile_photo').files[0]);

        $.ajax({
                url:"https://imageupload.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:({'file':filename,'email_id':email_id }),
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $('#uploaded_image').html("<label class='text-success'>file Uploading...</label>");
                },   
                success:function(data) {
                    $('#uploaded_image').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
});
</script>
```

imageupload.php

```
<?php
$filename=$_POST['file'];
$email_id=$_POST['email_id'].substr($filename, -5);

if(file_exists("upload/" . $email_id)){
    echo  $filename . " is already exists.";
} else{
    move_uploaded_file($filename, "upload/" .  $email_id);
    echo $email_id."Your file was uploaded successfully.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**

Comment: You should start with the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: There is more to using FormData to send files using js than naming a variable `form_data`

Answer (score -1):

**imageupload.php**
Try Code below and make sure you set uploads folder permission to 777.

```
<?php
$filename=$_POST['file']['name'];
$tmppath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$email_id=$_POST['email_id'].substr($filename, -5);
if(file_exists("upload/" . $email_id)){
    echo  $filename . " is already exists.";
} else{
    move_uploaded_file($tmppath, "upload/".$email_id);
    echo $email_id."Your file was uploaded successfully.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Really! ... No attempt to format that code so its vaguely readable??

Comment: You should also check that the file was successfully moved to the folder: if(move_uploaded_file() === true)

Comment: @MichaelKrutikov And that there were no errors while uploading it `$_POST['file']['error']`

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is not working file not uploaded  in my server